# Log Output from bourne shell script to file and console window

Tags: bash, logging, sh

The following works in bash and logs to both `mylog.log` and the current console when launched as `sh ./myscript.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
log="mylog.log"
exec &> >(tee -a "$log")
```

How can this be done with a bourne shell

```
#!/bin/sh
log="mylog.log"
???
```

Comment: AFIK you can't. This is a feature for bash, zsh and (I think) ksh.

Comment: how to do it in zsh?

Comment: Since this is a question of general interest, I suggest that you post it here on Stackoverflow. It deserves a response as an answer, not a mere comment (answers are searchable, while comments are not).

Comment: It just occured to me, that it is easy to do in `sh`. I will propose an answer.

Comment: Just use a named pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a named pipe:

```
log=mylog.log

trap 'rm -f "$tmp"' 0
tmp=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "$tmp"
tee -a "$log" < $tmp &

exec > "$tmp" 2>&1
```

Note that there are issues here: the name used to create the fifo might be added to the filesystem between the call to `mktemp` and `mkfifo`, the trap specification may be insufficient to handle SIGINT depending on the shell being used, etc. but this is usually sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you invoke your script recursively to do the redirection:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$self_redirect" ]
then
  export self_redirect=mylog.log 
  $0 "$@" | tee "$self_redirect"
  exit $?
fi
# .... Your normal script goes here...
```